# Null-aware operator with Lists

Tags: dart

In *Dart* the *null-aware* operator for methods in combination with the `??` operator does not work well.

Image having a call chain like this:

```
object.getter.getter.getter.getter
```

Now when `object` could be null and I do not want an exception I have to write this:

```
object?.getter?.getter?.getter?.getter
```

That is a null check for every getter, even though only `object` can be null, but then the `getter`'s obviously do not work.

I am okay with this. But now I have a scenario, where I want to return another value if null, but I am working with a list:

```
list[index][index][index]
```

#### How do I use the null-aware operator on the List getter?

*This does not work:*

```
list?[index]
```

and this does not exist for `List`'s in *Dart*.

```
list?.get(index)
```

#### I want to achieve something like this:

```
list?[index]?[index]?[index] ?? 0
```

Where I know that only `list` will ever be `null`.

This **long** code would work:

```
list == null ? 0 : list[index][index][index]
```

Comment: for all facing this, i don't know what with the below answer, but the thing is there is no null-safety solution for this, not even by using `elementAt`. you need to manually handle it

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**UPDATE - 2021/05/24**

If you are using null-safety, you can now use this:

```
list?[index]?[index]?[index] ?? 0
```

---

**Pre null-safety answer:**

There is no null-aware operator for the indexing operator (`[]`)

You can use `elementAt()` instead:

```
list?.elementAt(index)?.elementAt(index)?.elementAt(index) ?? 0
```

Comment: This is what I have been looking for. I have to say I find it very hard for myself to research these answers for *Dart*. Side question: Is there something like an exception-aware operator as well? Because on `List`'s the index can be out of range and it does not return `null`, but an exception is thrown.

Comment: No, there is no exception-aware operator. You have to use `try-catch`. You can create a function yourself that catches an exception and returns  `null` `T exceptionAware<T>(T Function() f) { try { return f(); } catch(_)  { return null; })` and use it like `var result = exceptionAware<int>(() => list[index][index][index]) ?? 0;`. I don't say it's a good idea to do that though ;-)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I thought `elementAt(index)` will return null if the list doesn't contain the item, but actually I got an error:  `RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0`, so I still need to use if ( .... ) to check ;(

Comment: No, `elementAt(index)?.` only helps when the element at `index` is the value `null`.

Comment: finally, I use `exceptionAware` in your comment: `val url = exceptionAware<String>(() => list?.first?.url)`; to get a value in only one line code without if check, thanks

Comment: another solution inspired by Kotlin `List.firstOrNull` extension function:
  /// Returns the first element, or `null` if the list is empty.
  T firstOrNull<T>(List<T> list) {
      if (list.isEmpty) {
        return null;
      } else {
        return list.first;
      }
  }

Comment: @li2 `List.firstOrNull` doesn't seem to exist in Dart, not sure what you mean there.

Comment: @Hasen yup exactly, you can create the function by yourself, you can check the implementation in the last part of my previous comment.

Comment: Hi, what about Maps? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're also unsure about the index, you can use the following for null aware

```
// Extension

extension ListExtension<T> on List<T> {
  T? getOrNull(int index) {
    return (index >= 0 && index < length) ? this[index] : null;
  }
}

// OR built in method

elementAtOrNull(index) // will throw error if index < 0
```

Example use

```
list?.getOrNull(index)
list?.getOrNull(index) ?? defaultValue

list?.elementAtOrNull(index) // make sure that the index >=0
```

If you want to get element by condition

```
list?.firstWhereOrNull((e) => e.name == 'A');
```