# Null-aware operator with Maps

Tags: dart

I had [the same problem with lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50315881/6509751), now it is [`Map`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/Map-class.html).

#### What I would like to do

The following *syntax is not **Dart***, as in *it does not compile*:

```
map?[key] ?? otherValue
```

If my `map` was not a **`Map`** but a *`List`*, it would look like [Günter pointed out here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50315935/6509751):

```
list?.elementAt(index) ?? otherValue
```

#### What I am searching for

I understand that `map?[key]` is not valid syntax and therefore I am searching for something like [`elementAt`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/Iterable/elementAt.html), which works for lists, for maps.

```
map?.valueFor(key) ?? otherValue
```

#### valueOf

That does obviously not yet exist. The problem has solutions and [`valueOf` might be a good one as well](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/33734).

Comment: Of course you can make it work with code that's ugly to varying degrees, but a satisfying answer will have to wait for a future version of Dart: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/36541

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This works:

```
(map ?? const {})[key] ?? otherValue;
```

Because the `key` will fallback to accessing an *empty `Map`*, which will always return `null`.

Comment: That does work and looks nice. I wonder how it did not come to my mind and if I should create an issue for that.

Comment: You mean an issue for `map?[key]`. I think it's highly unlikely to be added. `?` is only supported with `.`. Supporting it for `list?[index]` was requested but declined as far as I remember.

Comment: For something like `map.valueOf(key)`.

Comment: I see. Might be worth a try.

Comment: Consider using `const {}` to avoid creating a new map every time, at least when the types allow it.

Answer (score 2):

I use this function for null-safe nested map access:

```
// Returns value of map[p1][p2]...[pn]
// where path = [p1, p2, ..., pn]
//
// example: mapGet(map, ["foo", 9, 'c'])
dynamic mapGet(Map map, List path) {
  assert(path.length > 0);
  var m = map ?? const {};
  for (int i = 0; i < path.length - 1; i++) {
      m = m[path[i]] ?? const {};
  }

  return m[path.last];
}
```

Comment: You should probably use `T mapGet<T> (Map<dynamic, T>, List path) {` instead of just `dynamic`.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might work as an extension function:

```
extension MapExtensions<T, K> on Map<T, K> {
  K getOrNull(T key) {
     if (this == null || !this.containsKey(key)) {
       return null;
     } else {
       return this[key];
     }
  }

  K getOrElse(T key, K fallback) {
    return this.getOrNull(key) ?? fallback;
  }
}
```

Note: I haven't tested this, but should work.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another syntax I used a few times:

```
map?.containsKey(key) ?? false ? map[key] : otherValue
```

Although functionally equivalent to the one proposed by @Günter Zöchbauer it is a bit more cumbersome.
Anyway, since it might look clearer in a few circumstances, it is worth to mention.

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
map != null ? map[key]: otherValue;
```

which checks to see if the map is null before attempting to access the variable, which is the same as Günter's answer but checks first.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Arturs answer, I think we should improve it and discuss alternative implementations.

### Extension on non-null `Map<K,V>`

- In extensions on non-nullable types `this` is never null, so we should not check against it. (see bottom for more information)
- I use `K` for the key type and `V` for the value type
- make all parameters and return values nullable.

```
extension MapExt<K, V> on Map<K, V> {
  V? getOrNull(K? key) {
    if (!containsKey(key) || key == null) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return this[key];
    }
  }

  V? getOrElse(K? key, V? fallback) {
    return getOrNull(key) ?? fallback;
  }
}
```

Null-safe usage would then look like this:

```
myMap?.getOrNull(someKey)
```

Note that it is required to put a `?` here because the extensions is implemented on non-null maps, which is consistent with the rest of the nullsafe-apis.

### (Not really an ) alternative: implement extension on nullable `Map<K,V>?`

It is possible to implement the extension on nullable maps (i.e. `Map<K,V>?`)  which then would require to check `this` for null:

```
extension MapExt<K, V> on Map<K, V>? {
  V? getOrNull(K? key) {
    if (this == null || !this!.containsKey(key) || key == null) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return this![key];
    }
  }

  V? getOrElse(K? key, V? fallback) {
    return getOrNull(key) ?? fallback;
  }
}
```

This implementation allows accessing the extension methods on a potential null map directly without `?`:

```
Map<int,int>? = ...
myMap.getOrNull(someKey); // no compiler error
```

I think this is not consistent with the rest of the null-safe operators. I would suggest not using it, but preferring the first variant, which reveals that the map might be null.

Answer (score 0):

I have written my own version based on the answers above. It is used mostly for the JSON object handling.

```dart
dynamic mapOrListGet(dynamic map, List path) {
    assert(path.length > 0);
    assert(map is List || map is Map);
    var m = map ?? const {};
    var firstEl = path.removeAt(0);
    var result = (m is List)
        ? (firstEl < m.length ? m.elementAt(firstEl) : null)
        : m[firstEl];
    if (path.length == 0 || result == null) {
      return result;
    } else {
      return mapOrListGet(result, path);
    }
  }
```

And [here](https://dartpad.dev/01756b04e052a5971d6c3a390c4e0c2f) is how it works.