# Conditional member access for map children?

Tags: dart

Lets say you are trying to access deeply nested children in a map and you are not able to expect their parents to be there. Example:

```
Map awesomeMap = {
    "this":{
        "is":{
            "sometimes":"not here"
        }
    }
}

Map notAwesomeMap = {
    "this":{
        "haha":{
            "we":"switched"
        }
    }
}
```

When I go to access `notAwesomeMap['this']['is']['sometimes']` it will return an error because `['this']['is']` is `null`, and you cannot look for the value `['sometimes']` of `null`.

So that's fine, but I was hoping to be able to use conditional member access operators...

`notAwesomeMap['this']?.['is']?.['sometimes']`

but that doesn't work...

Short of wrapping everything in a try block, is there a good way to handle these situations?

Edit: I tried playing around with this and I didn't find anything really illuminating, but maybe this gives someone an idea

```
void main() {
  Map nestedMap = {
    'this':{
      'is':{
        'sometimes':'here'
      }
    }
  };

  final mapResult = nestedMap['this'];
  print(mapResult); //returns {is: {sometimes: here}}

  final nullResult = nestedMap['this']['is an'];
  print(nullResult); // returns null


  final nullifiedResult = nullify(nestedMap['this']['is an']['error']);
  print(nullifiedResult); // returns error, but is this possible another way?

  final errorResult = nestedMap['this']['is an']['error'];
  print(errorResult); // returns error
}



nullify(object){
  try {
    final result = object;
    return result;
  }
  catch (e) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/28389 is the issue requesting special syntax for this.

Comment: It appears that this feature is on the roadmap: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/accepted/future-releases/nnbd/feature-specification.md

Answer (score 2):

One way would be

```
final result = (((nestedMap ?? const {})['this'] ?? const {})['is an'] ?? const {})['error'];
```

See also [Null-aware operator with Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51141109/null-aware-operator-with-maps/51141153#51141153)

Answer (score 2):

You could write a simple function to help do what you want:

```
R lookup<R, K>(Map<K, dynamic> map, Iterable<K> keys, [R defaultTo]);
```

Example usage:

```
final result = lookup(inputMap, ['this', 'is', 'something']);
```

Example implementation:
https://dartpad.dartlang.org/1a937b2d8cdde68e6d6f14d216e4c291

```
void main() {
  var nestedMap = {
    'this':{
      'is':{
        'sometimes':'here'
      }
    }
  };

  print(lookup(nestedMap, ['this']));
  print(lookup(nestedMap, ['this', 'is']));
  print(lookup(nestedMap, ['this', 'is', 'sometimes']));
  print(lookup(nestedMap, ['this', 'is', 'error']));

  // Bail out on null:
  print(lookup(nestedMap, ['error'], 'Default Value'));
}

R lookup<R, K>(Map<K, dynamic> map, Iterable<K> keys, [R defaultTo]) {
  dynamic current = map;
  for (final key in keys) {
    if (current is Map<K, dynamic>) {
      current = current[key];
    } else {
      return defaultTo;
    }
  }
  return current as R;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like @matanlurey's approach, but have made two changes:

1. Drop the `defaultTo` since you can still use `??` which is more readable.
2. Swallow type-cast errors.

```dart
R lookup <R, K>(Map<K, dynamic> map, Iterable<K> keys) {
  dynamic current = map;
  for (final key in keys) {
    if (current is Map<K, dynamic>) {
      current = current[key];
    }
  }
  try{
    return current as R;
  } catch(e){
    // do nothing
  }
}
```

Usage is similar

```dart
String someValue = lookup(nestedMap, ['some', 'value']) ?? 'Default Value';
```