# Null-aware operator when traversing a nested map

Tags: dart

How do you check for nulls when accessing second level map elements?
E.g.

```
var clientName = item['client']['name'];
```

will throw an exception if `item` does not contain `client`
I'd like something like

```
item['client']?['name']
```

or

```
item['client']?.['name']
```

But that won't compile.

Surely I can do `item['client']` twice or introduce a local var for it but that feels subpar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is *similar* to [a question I asked some time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51141109/6509751).

Basically, this would be the solution for your case:

```dart
(item['client'] ?? const {})['name']
```

This makes use of the [null-aware](https://blog.sethladd.com/2015/07/null-aware-operators-in-dart.html) `??` operator which just returns an empty map in the case that `'client'` is not present in `item`.

Comment: Right, it looks like a duplicate. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

With `putIfAbsent`, you can use `?` operator.

```dart
item.putIfAbsent("client", (){})
    ?.putIfAbsent("name", (){});
```

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.1/dart-core/Map/putIfAbsent.html

Comment: No, I don't want to alter the map content